# Vim cindent after scope declartion not working

Tags: vim

I would like to indent my C++ code to have 1 shiftwidth after the scope specifier (`private`, `public`, `protected`) like the following code (assuming `shiftwidth=3`)

```
class blah
{
public:
   blah();
private:
   m_bl;
};
```

I'm currently using `set cino=g0,h1`.

However, vim always indents the lines after scope specifier to be as if `gs` was used, i.e, vim always adds 6 spaces instead of 3. The result looks like below:

```
class blah
{
public:
      blah();
private:
      m_b1;
};
```

I have tried several different options like:

`set cino=g0,h0`

`set cino=g0,h-1`

`set cino=g0,h0.5s`

None of them seem to be working. Vim always indents by 6 spaces (`shiftwidth=3`).
How do I achieve the indent results to get 1 `shiftwidth` after scope specifier?
I'm using Vim version **8.0.69** if that helps.

Comment: Does `:set indentexpr?` return something? If you're using an `'indentexpr'` (e.g. from a C++ indent plugin) then it's quite possible it will ignore `'cino'` and just make its own choices...

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: @filbranden `set indentexpr?` returns nothing (`indentexpr=`). Not sure what the problem is as all `g0` is recognized by `cindent`.

Comment: This works for me, I get 3 space indent on the methods. I'm using `set ai cin cino=g0,h1s sw=3`. Typing the class above properly indents `blah();` and `m_b1;` by 3 spaces. I can also use `gg=G` (the `=` operator with a motion) to re-indent it and that works ok. Using `set cino=g0` is already enough to make this work for me. I'm using Vim 8.1.1749. Maybe try to load vim without any plugins (`vim -u NONE -U NONE -N`) then set the options above and see if it works for you then? Just to rule out any other interference from your vimrc and plugins...

Comment: @filbranden, I tried your suggestion of starting vim without any plugins or .vimrc with the exact same `cino` settings. The results are the same. There are always 6 spaces. I will try to upgrade to 8.1.1749 and check. Seems like a bug? (Not sure)